# Rebinding events in jQuery after Ajax update (updatepanel)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have several input and option elements on my page, each (well almost) have an event attached to update some text on the page once they change. I use jQuery which is really really cool :)

I also use Microsofts [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) framework, utilizing the UpdatePanel. The reason why I do that is that certain elements are created on the page based on some server-side logic. I don't really want to explain why I use the UpdatePanel - even if it could (it can with quite some effort) be rewritten to use only [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) I still want that UpdatePanel.

You probably guessed it - once I have a postback on the UpdatePanel the jQuery events stops working. I actually was expecting this, since the "postback" is not really a new postback so my code in document.ready that binds the events won't be fired again. I also confirmed my suspicion by reading up on it in the jQuery help libraries.

Anyway I'm left with the problem of rebinding my controls after the UpdatePanel is done updating the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). I preferably need a solution that does not require adding more .js files (jQuery plug-ins) to the page but something as simple as being able to catch the UpdatePanel's 'afterupdating' where I can just call my method to rebind all the form elements.

Comment: This is very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Since you're using ASP.NET AJAX, you'll have access to a `pageLoad` event handler, that gets called each time the page posts back, be it full or partial from an UpdatePanel. You just need to put the function in to your page, no hooking up is required.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
   if (args.get_isPartialLoad())
   {
       //Specific code for partial postbacks can go in here.
   }
}
```

Comment: No problem - that's just one way of doing it btw. If you need more flexibility, check out the endRequest event on the PageRequestManager class.

Comment: Awesome! I replaced my jquery $(document).ready with your pageLoad (without the if block) and it solved my problem!

Comment: Caution: only one "pageLoad" function executes on page - the last one defined. So if actions that need to be executed reside on different controls - there are easier ways to achieve required behavior - like "Sys.Application.add_load".

Answer (score 23):

Or you could check the latest jQuery's live functionality via the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Comment: This was the best solution for me, as much of my jQuery markup is encapsulated inside several user controls on the page.

Comment: can you post example with datepicker?

Comment: I was just using "on" for binding to a drop down list inside a panel that does async post triggering. It WAS NOT working until, I also included the answer above by @Phil Jenkins. I am not sure if it makes a differenc if it is a async post or full post back, but the on. binder was not handling it after the post back.

Answer (score 22):

```
Sys.Application.add_load(initSomething);
function initSomething()
{
  // will execute on load plus on every UpdatePanel postback
}
```

Answer (score 14):

As of jQuery 1.7, the recommended way to do this is to use [jQuery's .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) syntax.

Make sure, however, that you set up the event on the **document** object, not the DOM object itself.  For example, *this will break after the UpdatePanel postback*:

```
$(':input').on('change', function() {...});
```

... because the ':inputs' have been rewritten.  Do this instead:

```
$(document).on('change', ':input', function() {...});
```

As long as the document is around, any inputs (including those from UpdatePanel refreshes) will trigger the change handler.

Comment: Awesome !  (the document) worked lovely using the following .... $(document).on('click','#tagsAdd',function () no matter how many update panels I have breaking up the content of the page :)  Thx

Answer (score 9):

Use following code

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);

function pageLoaded(sender, args) {
    var updatedPanels = args.get_panelsUpdated();
    // check if Main Panel was updated 
    for (idx = 0; idx < updatedPanels.length; idx++) {
        if (updatedPanels[idx].id == "<%=upMain.ID %>") {
            rebindEventsForMainPanel();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use jQuery and event delegation. Basically hook events to containers rather than every element and query the event.target and run script based on that.

It has multiple benefits in that you reduce the code noise (no need to rebind). It is 
also easier on browser memory (less events bound in the DOM.)

Quick example [here](http://pastebin.me/4922b20867e9d).

[jQuery plugin](http://www.danwebb.net/2008/2/8/event-delegation-made-easy-in-jquery) for easy event delegation.

P.S I am 99% sure delegation will be in the jQuery core at the next release.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code, You need to validate the control will use the datapicker:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

         Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(addDataPicker); 
         function addDataPicker(sender, args)
         {
            var fchFacturacion = document.getElementById('<%= txtFechaFacturacion.ClientID %>');
            if (fchFacturacion != null) {
               $(fchFacturacion).datepicker({ onSelect: function () { }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, showOn: 'button', buttonImage: '../Imagenes/calendar.gif', buttonImageOnly: true});}
         } 

    </script>

     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upEjem" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
       <ContentTemplate>
              <div id="div1" runat="server" visible="false">
                  <input type="text" id="txtFechaFacturacion" 
                      name="txtFechaFacturacion" visible="true"
                      readonly="readonly" runat="server" />
              </div>
       </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
             function pageLoad() {

                 if (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {


       }

            </script>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

into of the "if" you can put the code that you need execute every time that the updatepanel does AsyncPostBack.

Answer (score 2):

Bind your events using jQuery's new 'live' method.  It will bind events to all your present elements and all future ones too.  Cha ching! :)