# Jquery Fancybox not working after postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I have a Fancybox (or more accurately) a number of fancy boxes on an asp.net page.

My [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) (jquery plugin) works fine until a postback occurs on the page then it refuses to work.

Any thoughts? Anyone experienced similar behaviour?

**UPDATE : Some Code..**

I have a databound repeater with a fancybox on each repeating item.

They are instanciated by (outside the repeater)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("a.watchvideo").fancybox({
            'overlayShow': false,
            'frameWidth' : 480,
            'frameHeight' : 400
            });
        });
```

The anchor tag is repeated..

> href="#watchvideo_<%#Eval("VideoId")%>"

As is a div with

```
id="watchvideo_<%#Eval("VideoId") %>
```

As is a script element that instanciates the flash movies

Yes the VideoIds are being output the the page.

**UPDATE : It's not a problem with the flash..**

It is not a problem with the flash as i've tried it without the flash, it wont even pop a window with a simple message in.

**UPDATE : I wonder if it is the updatepanel.**

[Rebinding events in jQuery after Ajax update (updatepanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301473/rebinding-events-in-jquery-after-ajax-update-updatepanel)

-- lee

Comment: Please post the offending code so we can help.  With out code all we can do is speculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the Update panel as described

here.. [Rebinding events in jQuery after Ajax update (updatepanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301473/rebinding-events-in-jquery-after-ajax-update-updatepanel)

As suggested I simply replaced

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("a.watchvideo").fancybox({
            'overlayShow': false,
            'frameWidth' : 480,
            'frameHeight' : 400
            });
        });
```

with

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
   if(args.get_isPartialLoad())
   {
       $("a.watchvideo").fancybox({
            'overlayShow': false,
            'frameWidth' : 480,
            'frameHeight' : 400
            });

   }
}
```

and it worked!

-- Lee

Answer (score 14):

The problem is in using `$(document).ready()` to bind the fancybox. This code is only executed once, when the page is originally loaded. If you want the fancybox functionality on every postback, synchronous or asynchronous, replace the `$(document).ready()` with `pageLoad(sender, args)`. i.e.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $("a.watchvideo").fancybox({
        'overlayShow': false,
        'frameWidth' : 480,
        'frameHeight' : 400
        });
}
```

[**see this answer for more info**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152946/how-to-have-a-javascript-callback-executed-after-an-update-panel-postback/1153002#1153002)

Comment: Cheers Russ, looks like you would have solved my problem had I not got there on my own. Much appreciated. Cheers,

-- Lee

Comment: No probs, glad to help. I highly recommend looking into the links on the other answer - the article is a good read and the ASP.NET AJAX documentation can prove extremely useful.

Comment: Thanks I just had this issue to and I'm not well versed on jQuery yet. This solved it! Thanks so much for posting this.

Comment: +1 This was a big help to me. I am also new to jQuery and was trying to hack together examples and your answer filled in my blanks.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the instantiating code is being inserted at a piece of code which is not run after a postback?

Comment: Interesting.. the fancybox instanciating code is on the aspx page.. I might try writing it to the page from the code behind..

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone else, but FancyBox appends it's code to the <body> element... which is all fine and well, but resides OUTSIDE the asp.net <form> element.  My postback problems went away when I modified FancyBox to append its dom objects to the <form> element:

```
$('body form:first').append( ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a paged grid-view. The first page of the grid was launching the fancybox while the remaing did not.

I thought it could be an issue related to the UpdatePanel which refreshes only a portion of the screen.

I solved the issue replacing this:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("a.small").fancybox();

        });
    </script>
```

with this:

```
  <script>
        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            $("a.small").fancybox();
        };
    </script>
```