# Javascript not running after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have some Javascript that works perfectly before a postback happens in ASP.Net, however when a postback event occurs from a button click the script no longer runs.

this is the code I am using

```
function displayCheckboxInSubject() {
    var CountSelectedCB = [];
    console.log("in displayCheckBoxInSubject with loader");
    $(".subjectCB").on("change loader", function () {
    //$(".subjectCB").change(function () {
        selectedCB = [];
        notSelectedCB = [];
        CountSelectedCB.length = 0;
        $(".subjectCB").each(function () {
            //alert("in here two")
            if ($(this).find("input").is(":checked")) {
                //alert("in here three")
                CountSelectedCB.push($(this).find("input").val());
            }
        });

        $("#txtSubject").val(CountSelectedCB.join(", "));
    }).trigger("loader");

}

$(document).ready(displayCheckboxInSubject);
```

I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction of how to resolve this.

thanks

Simon

Comment: i am not using an ajax update panel, so i do not see how this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

It is because document.ready() is not executed after a postback.

Microsoft suggest using PageRequestManager to set up a request handler. But you can alternatively initialise your control from the back-end and fire it that way.

I can't take credit for it, but please see this answer:
[answered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485778/2878135)

UPDATE: Can you use an UpdatePanel? That should make it work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pageLoad() {
    $('#TextBox1').unbind();
    $('#TextBox1').datepicker(); 
  }
</script>

<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Basic example from [Encosia](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)

Comment: where do i need to put this instead? or should i just remove it?

Comment: this isnt working for me, nor am i doing an async postback

Comment: maybe - what I am trying to do is when a user clicks send on an asp.net webform to send data to a database, if this fails, the page was posting back and not keeping the values.  The page is now keeping the values, but now has stopped the javascript working.  So, if I use an update panel, where would I use this? would I put my checkbox list in the panel, or would i use it else where?

Comment: Put the UpdatePanel in your form, and your controls inside that.
See this link: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers