# get checkbox click inside repeater by jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

I have a repeater that contain a checkbox and I need just to enable some control depend on that checkbox checked status,I used to do so with jQuery using

```
$("input:checkbox").Click(function(){
    alert('Any code');
});
```

**Now** I have an updatepanel contain the repeater that have the checkbox

**So**  I need to get the click event

the way I show here doesn't work !! I don't know why ?

I'm using jQuery 1.4.1 and IE9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe updatepanel dynamically adds stuff to your page so you'll need to use jquery [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$("input:checkbox").live("click",function(){
    alert('Any code');
});
```

Or you can use [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$("#ParentToRepeater").delegate("input:checkbox","click",function(){
     alert('Any code');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer can help you...

[Rebinding events in jQuery after Ajax update (updatepanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301473/rebinding-events-in-jquery-after-ajax-update-updatepanel)