# When i include jquery.js in markup other javascript functions in the page are not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a large asp.net 2.0 application. In the current page i have one

`<head id="head1" runat="server">` with some meta information and the original developer has written all Javascript functions in the `<body>` tag. Now i want to implement

```
$(document).ready(function load()
    // My code 
});
```

and when i include jquery-1.8.3.js in my head/body tag , the other javascript functions are not working properly. what could i do to solve this?

```
 <head id="Head1" runat="server">`
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="JScript/jquery-1.8.3.js"/>`
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
 <title>HMS</title>
 <link href="Css/MyStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
```

**Body**

```
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="JScript/MediReckonerJscript.js">
</script>
//some javascript functions here that are not firing since i added jquery reference in the head section. if that is removed this function works well.
```

**My script in body that usesjQuery Library.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
//This is my script in the <body> tag.
jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function load() {
  var iFrame = $('#PageFrame');

iFrame.bind('load', function() { //binds the event
    alert('iFrame Reloaded');
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: First of, you have to give some more information. What errors do you get? I see you forgot `{` after `load()`, but maybe that's just a typo.

Comment: how many jquery libraries do you include in your page?

Comment: and also is your page contain UpdatePanel or ajax calls

Comment: I Would need more context to understand the Problem, what functions dont work? Those the original Code use a diverent jQery Version, those the original code defined its own `$`-function ....

Comment: The problem comes because of JQuery library conflict with other JavaScript library.
Please visit [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: check your browser console

Comment: @mario I dont get any errors. The javascript functions to simulate menu and submenu are not running. If i add it jquery.js file in the head the menu styles are dead. if i add jquery.js in the body, any script below that are not firing

Comment: @arjuncc i have included only one jquery file. jquery-1.8.3.js

Comment: @Devjosh Yes, the current page has ajax libraries and calls..

Comment: You must get an javascript-error. Look in the developer tool in your browser. For example, the console in Chrome or IE (hit F12).

Comment: @codebrain please refer this previous link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301473/rebinding-events-in-jquery-after-ajax-update-updatepanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have other libraries in your page add this.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Libraries like prototype use the same '$' used by jQuery and so, they conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this could be the version problem please check with some lower version of the same library also you can use jQuery.noConflict(); for jQuery is conflicting OR $.noConflict(); if $ is conflicting.

Use noConflict() like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
//This is my script in the <body> tag.
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function load() {
  var iFrame = j('#PageFrame');

iFrame.bind('load', function() { //binds the event
    alert('iFrame Reloaded');
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think that's sounds clever. will check.

Comment: but this is not stopping my submenu loading scripts. Instead if i add jQuery.noConflict(); at the end of head section everything seems to work well!. ?