# bootstrap popover doesn't work in asp.net updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, updatepanel, popover

I'm using bootstrap popover in a update panel in my asp page that it doesn't work. when I put it out of update panel it's OK, please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a lot to go on here, but when I've run into similar issues in the past it's been because the update panel does a partial postback for an update and the javascript isn't getting bound because the markup changed or was added after the page load. You will need to rebind the trigger (initialize the popover) when the AJAX panel updates using the methods described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301473/rebinding-events-in-jquery-after-ajax-update-updatepanel).

Comment: thank very much Mr Christopher. my problem has solved.