# Appending javascript code piece to the end of the body tag

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am looking for a way to insert javascript code block to end of ASP.NET page.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "showVideo", sScript, true);
```

is appending to body but js codes are always requesting some js files didn't load or some functions are below of the script.

How can i append scripts that i generated dynamically to the bottom of body?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between RegisterStartupScript and RegisterClientScriptBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666519/difference-between-registerstartupscript-and-registerclientscriptblock)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We are using something like

```
    public static void GenerateJsTag(this TemplateControl page, string jsCode)
    {
        var jsLink = new HtmlGenericControl {TagName = "script", InnerHtml = jsCode };
        jsLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
        page.Controls.Add(jsLink);
    }
```

hope that will help ;)

Comment: Thank you Thomas. Your solution is also very good. I found the answer now and posted but i will mark your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

[Adding Client-Side Script Blocks with RegisterStartupScript() and RegisterClientScriptBlock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx#aspnet-injectclientsidesc_topic2)

The only difference between these two methods is where each one emits the script block. **RegisterClientScriptBlock()** emits the script block ***at the beginning of the Web Form*** (right after the  tag), while **RegisterStartupScript()** emits the script block ***at the end of the Web Form*** (right before the `</form>` tag).

Comment: Very important to note that RegisterScript methods are related to <form></form> not body or html tags.  @uzay95 thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You'd think these methods would have more descriptive names like RegisterScriptAtBeginning() and RegisterScriptAtEnd() because I *still* can't remember which is which. But that's Microsoft I guess