# Calling javascript for popup window in C#

Tags: asp.net

I wrote a javscript which create a popup with certain information.

```
function Showduplicate() {
            isDuplicate = true;
            var modal = document.getElementById('duplicate');
            modal.style.display = '';
            modal.style.position = 'fixed';
            modal.style.zIndex = '100';
            modal.style.left = '30%';
            modal.style.top = '40%';

            var screen = document.getElementById('modalScreen');
            screen.style.display = '';
            return false;


    }
```

modal is a div element. duplicate is also a div element which contains certain checkboxes etc. . Now I check a query in codebehind and call this javascript function accordingly. I tried to use Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock Method but was unsuccessful. So can you guys help me out in calling the javascript function in codebehind.

Comment: In general you can call C# functions from JS, but not vice-versa - at least not without significant effort. What exactly are you trying to do with this code? It looks like an input validation helper.

Comment: I am actually dealing  with duplication in grid where i need to take the decision of the user whether or  not to create the record

Comment: Is this after a PostBack, or is it a response a a JS action?

Answer (score 0):

I think for your scenario, you should be using `Page.RegisterStartupScript()`. See [this pos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666519/difference-between-registerstartupscript-and-registerclientscriptblock)t for more info on the distinction between `RegisterStartupScript()` and `RegisterClientScriptBlock()`.

Comment: Page.RegisterStartupScript("myscript", "<script language=JavaScript>" + "function Showduplicate(){alert('hi');} </script>");

Comment: I did this but still not able to call the pop up window

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Asp.Net WebForms and Asp.Net Ajax. (The same technique can be applied to other scenarios as well).

Let's say you have a button like:

```
<tr>
    <td><input id="grid_1">Value</input></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:addItem(1)">Add</a></td>
</tr>
```

Then you can control the popup with the following JS code:

```
function OnAddSuccess(result) {
    // Update display
}

function OnAddError(error) {
    Showduplicate();
}

function addItem(id) {
    $get("LoadingLabel").innerHTML = "Loading...";
    PageMethods.TryAddItem(id, $get("grid_"+id).innerHTML, OnAddSuccess, OnAddError);
}
```

You should not forget:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```