# Calling JavaScript Function From CodeBehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Can someone provide good examples of calling a JavaScript function From CodeBehind and Vice-versa?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

You may try this :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","MyFunction()",true);
```

Comment: I would go for the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "somekey", script, true); approach. It works during partial postbacks as well.

Comment: 1. Sometimes `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` is required instead  [see this post for info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666519/difference-between-registerstartupscript-and-registerclientscriptblock).  2. It might be worth mentioning that in order for MyFunction() to  work, MyFunction() has to be defined before the form tags or inside of them, but NOT after the </form> ending tag (otherwise a Object expected error will occur)

Comment: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "text", "openDep()", true);` works. `this.GetType()` throws an error for me.

Comment: This not works when the code wrapped with an `asp:UpdatePanel` and written in a button event. Which causes the page to postback.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I am confused on where this code goes. Is it in the C# CodeBehind? Is it in the JS file that has the function? Is it in the aspx page?

Comment: It goes in the c# codebehind. Place it where you want the js to be executed.

Answer (score 60):

**Calling a JavaScript function from code behind**

Step 1 Add your Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function Func() {
        alert("hello!")
    }
</script>
```

Step 2 Add 1 **Script Manager** in your webForm and Add 1 **button** too

Step 3 Add this code in your button click event

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "Func()", true);
```

Comment: When trying to do this when a GridView row is clicked, it only works when using `ScriptManager` as in this answer, not `Page.ClientScript` as in other answers. Might be related to the `asp:UpdatePanel` comment under the accepted answer.

Answer (score 59):

C# to JavaScript: you can register script block to run on page like following:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"hwa","alert('Hello World');",true);
```

replace `alert()` part with your function name.

For calling C# method from JavaScript you can use `ScriptManager` or `jQuery`. I personally use `jQuery`. You need to decorate the method that you want to call from JavaScript with `WebMethod` attribute. For more information regarding calling C# method (called `PageMethod`) from `jQuery` you can refer to [Dave Ward's](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) post.

Answer (score 18):

If you need to send a value as a parameter.

```
string jsFunc = "myFunc(" + MyBackValue + ")";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "myJsFn", jsFunc, true);
```

Answer (score 17):

You can not do this directly. In standard WebForms JavaScript is interpreted by browser and C# by server. What you can do to call a method from server using JavaScript is.

- Use [`WebMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.webmethodattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) as [`attribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) in target methods.
- Add [`ScriptManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager?view=netframework-4.7.2) setting [`EnablePageMethods`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablepagemethods?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_ScriptManager_EnablePageMethods) as `true`.
- Add JavaScript code to call the methods through the object `PageMethods`.

Like this:

### Step 1

```cs
public partial class Products : System.Web.UI.Page 
{ 
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()] 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()] 
    public static List<Product> GetProducts(int cateogryID) 
    {
        // Put your logic here to get the Product list 
    }
```

### Step 2: Adding a [`ScriptManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager?view=netframework-4.7.2) on the [`Page`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

### Step 3: Calling the method using JavaScript

```js
function GetProductsByCategoryID(categoryID)
{
    PageMethods.GetProducts(categoryID, OnGetProductsComplete);
}
```

[Take a look at this link.](http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx)

To call a JavaScript function from server you can use [`RegisterStartupScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```cs
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"id","callMyJSFunction()",true);
```

Comment: Where do you place step one in MVC 3 file hierarchy?

Comment: @Rob The `GetProducts()` function is just a code-behind function that would live in a controller in an MVC app, so the tags go on top of whatever function you'd want to put in a controller that you'd be intending to call from JavaScript.

Comment: How is `List<Product>` passed to the client-side javascript function? Does client-side function `OnGetProductsComplete` receive a JSON string as its first parameter?

Answer (score 9):

Another thing you could do is to create a session variable that gets set in the code behind and then check the state of that variable and then run your javascript. The good thing is this will allow you to run your script right where you want to instead of having to figure out if you want it to run in the DOM or globally.

Something like this:
Code behind:

```
Session["newuser"] = "false"
```

In javascript

```
var newuser = '<%=Session["newuser"]%>';
 if (newuser == "yes")
     startTutorial();
```

Answer (score 8):

You cannot. Codebehind is running on the server while JavaScript is running on the client.

However, you can add `<script type="text/javascript">someFunction();</script>` to your output and thus cause the JS function to be called when the browser is parsing your markup.

Comment: "You cannot.  But here is how you do it."

Comment: I wouldn't consider that calling a method from the server-side code since you don't have a real way to get a return value or specify a callback.

Comment: Aw, sure you can.  You can call a postback from your javascript or AJAX anything back.  I thought it was funny; I tend to do the same thing--"No, that's impossible.  Nobody would even want to do that if they could." then a few minutes later "So here's how we are going to do it."

Answer (score 8):

You can use literal:

```
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction();</script>"));
```

Comment: But doesn't this just add a script into memory, it doesn't actually run it as well?

Answer (score 7):

Working Example :_

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage2.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="History.aspx.cs" Inherits="NAMESPACE_Web.History1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function helloFromCodeBehind() {
                alert("hello!")
            }


        </script>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

 <div id="container"  ></div>

</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace NAMESPACE_Web
{
    public partial class History1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "displayalertmessage", "helloFromCodeBehind()", true);
        }

    }
}
```

Possible pitfalls:-

1. Code and HTML might not be in same namespace
2. `CodeBehind="History.aspx.cs"` is pointing to wrong page
3. JS function is having some error

Comment: Thank you for posting the only working example I could understand how to implement

Answer (score 5):

IIRC Code Behind is compiled serverside and javascript is interpreted client side. This means there is no direct link between the two.

What you can do on the other hand is have the client and server communicate through a nifty tool called AJAX. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_JavaScript_and_XML

Answer (score 5):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.Page.GetType(),"updatePanel1Script", "javascript:ConfirmExecute()",true/>
```

Comment: Add some explanation

Answer (score 4):

I've been noticing a lot of the answers here are using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` and if you are going to do that, that isn't the right way to do it.  The right way is to use `ScriptManager.RegisterScriptBlock([my list of args here])`.  The reason being is you should only be using RegisterStartupScript when your page loads (hence the name RegisterStartupScript).

In VB.NET:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(String), "myScriptName" + key, $"myFunctionName({someJavascriptObject})", True)
```

in C#:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(string), "myScriptName" + key, $"myFunctionName({someJavascriptObject})", true);
```

Of course, I hope it goes without saying that you need to replace key with your key identifier and should probably move all of this into a sub/function/method and pass in key and someJavascriptObject (if your javascript method requires that your arg is a javascript object).

MSDN docs:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338357(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

This is how I've done it.

HTML markup showing a label and button control is as follows.

```
<body> 
  <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
  <div> 
    <asp:Label ID="lblJavaScript" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> 
    <asp:Button ID="btnShowDialogue" runat="server" Text="Show Dialogue" /> 
  </div> 
  </form> 
</body>
```

JavaScript function is here.

```
<head runat="server"> 
  <title>Calling javascript function from code behind example</title> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function showDialogue() { 
      alert("this dialogue has been invoked through codebehind."); 
    } 
  </script> 
</head>
```

Code behind to trigger the JavaScript function is here.

```
lblJavaScript.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>showDialogue();</script>";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "JavaFunction", "AlertError();", true);
```

**using your function is enough**

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit more?

Comment: What is this "JavaFunction" parameter ? Can we add anything in it? What needs to have in that argument?

Comment: @SenuraDissanayake It's a title-yes, it can be anything & doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

Try This in Code Behind and it will worked 100%

Write this line of code in you Code Behind file

```
string script = "window.onload = function() { YourJavaScriptFunctionName(); };";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "YourJavaScriptFunctionName", script, true);
```

And this is the web form page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function YourJavaScriptFunctionName() {
        alert("Test!")
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
object Json_Object=maintainerService.Convert_To_JSON(Jobitem);
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,GetType(), "Javascript", "SelectedJobsMaintainer("+Json_Object+"); ",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't find a solution that was code behind, which includes trying the `ClientScript` and `ScriptManager` like mutanic and Orlando Herrera said in this question (they both somehow failed), I'll offer a front-end solution that utilizes button clicks to others if they're in the same position as me. This worked for me:

HTML Markup:

```
<asp:button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return myFunction();"></asp:button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
    // Your JavaScript code
    return false;
}
```

I am simply using an ASP.NET button which utilizes the `OnClientClick` property, which fires client-side scripting functions, that being JavaScript. The key things to note here are the uses of the `return` keyword in the function call and in the function itself. I've read docs that don't use `return` but still get the button click to work - somehow it didn't work for me. The `return false;` statement in the function specifies a postback should NOT happen. You could also use that statement in the `OnClientClick` property: `OnClientClick="myFunction() return false;"`

Answer (score 0):

I used ScriptManager in Code Behind and it worked fine.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "confirm()", true);
```

If you are using UpdatePanel in ASP Frontend.
Then, enter UpdatePanel name and 'function name' defined with script tags.

Answer (score 0):

Thank "Liko", just add a comment to his answer.

```
string jsFunc = "myFunc(" + MyBackValue + ")";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "myJsFn", jsFunc, true);
```

Added single quotes (`'`) to variable, otherwise it will give error message:

```
string jsFunc = "myFunc('" + MyBackValue + "')";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't call a Javascript function from the CodeBehind, because the CodeBehind file contains the code that executes server side on the web server. Javascript code executes in the web browser on the client side.

Comment: You can't call a javascript function directly as in myCoolJavascriptFunction(javascriptFunctionArgs); on the server, but you can call a javascript function from the code behind in a WebForms page.

Comment: agreed with cloudstrifebro

Answer (score -1):

You can expose C# methods on codebehind pages to be callable via JavaScript by using the [ScriptMethod attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx).

You cannot call JavaScript from a CodeBehind - that code exists solely on the client.