# force checkbox click event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript function tied to the click event of each checkbox item in an asp:checkboxlist.  However, there's an option whereby the user can dynamically add a new item to the list.  I have already successfully done this code, the item is added, and the javascript function tied to the onclick event.  However, I need to run the onclick function once from the code behind, as I add the item to the list.  How can I simply run a pre existing javascript function from C# codebehind?

```
protected void btnAddLang_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Healthline.ServiceRecords.DataHelper helper = new Healthline.ServiceRecords.DataHelper();
        Hashtable prms = new Hashtable();
        DataSet dsLangs = new DataSet();

        prms = new Hashtable();
        prms.Add("@LangName", txtOtherLanguages.Text);

        dsLangs = helper.RunSP("mySP", prms);

        if (dsLangs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.Value = dsLangs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LanguageID"].ToString();
            item.Text = dsLangs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Language"].ToString();
            chkTopLanguages.Items.Add(item);
        }

        foreach (ListItem listitem in chkTopLanguages.Items)
        {
            listitem.Attributes.Add("onclick", "GetLanguages()");
        }

        //here I need to force an immediate call to the javascript function GetLanguages()
    }
```

If it helps.  Rather than a straight call to the javascript function, if I can force a trigger to the onclick event of the checkbox I just added, that should work as well, since the javascript function is called onclick of the checkbox item

Comment: please provide some code for your question

Comment: have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731224/calling-javascript-function-from-codebehind

Comment: Yes I looked at it, and tried some of the suggestions there, but nothing is working yet.

Comment: Are you using ScriptManager to ajaxify this click event? If so it won't work by the answer provided in for diogod's link.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an argument to the function, and passing in the control. That way you can handle the `onclick`, and you can call the function when the page is posted back, i.e. when the dynamic checkbox is first rendered.

Comment: That's not an answer, but a comment. The OP is asking how to "fire" off an onclick() event from code behind, which is what I am after.