# How to display an alert box from C# in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, alert

I am using a `detail-view` and would like to display an alert-box at the end of my code block that says:

> Thank you! Your data has been inserted successfully.

Is there a simple way to do this from the `C#` code behind of my `ASP.NET` web pages?

Comment: Look for `Client.RegisterScriptBlock(.....)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling JavaScript Function From CodeBehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731224/calling-javascript-function-from-codebehind)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

After insertion code,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record Inserted Successfully')", true);
```

Comment: this worked like a charm. thanks everyone for the quick help.

Answer (score 27):

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Data inserted successfully')</script>");
```

Comment: nice because I can check if there's a value in a certain variable for checking

Answer (score 9):

Write this line after your insert code

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Insert is successfull')", true);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create a global method to show message(alert) in your web form application.

```
public static class PageUtility
{
    public static void MessageBox(System.Web.UI.Page page,string strMsg)
    {
        //+ character added after strMsg "')"
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, page.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + strMsg + "')", true);

    }
}
```

**webform.aspx**

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PageUtility.MessageBox(this, "Success !");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a `Page.Redirect()`, use this

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Inserted successfully!')</script>"); //works great
```

But if you do have `Page.Redirect()`, use this

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Inserted..');window.location = 'newpage.aspx';</script>"); //works great
```

works for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record Inserted Successfully')", true);
```

You can use this way, but be sure that there is no `Page.Redirect()` is used.
If you want to redirect to another page then you can try this:

page.aspx:

```
<asp:Button AccessKey="S" ID="submitBtn" runat="server" OnClick="Submit" Text="Submit"
                                        Width="90px" ValidationGroup="vg" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick = "Confirm()" />
```

JavaScript code:

```
function Confirm()
{
   if (Page_ClientValidate())
   {
      var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
      confirm_value.type = "hidden";
      confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
      if (confirm("Data has been Added. Do you wish to Continue ?"))
      {
         confirm_value.value = "Yes";
      }
      else
      {
         confirm_value.value = "No";
      }
      document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
   }
}
```

and this is your code behind snippet :

```
protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
   if (confirmValue == "Yes")
   {
      Response.Redirect("~/AddData.aspx");
   }
   else
   {
      Response.Redirect("~/ViewData.aspx");
   }
}
```

This will sure work.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question because the requirement is to have a message after the data is saved successfully, whereas your approach asks for confirmation before saving data

Answer (score 0):

Hey Try This Code.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Alert", "Data has been saved", true);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following one with customized way, in asp.net C#,

```
<style>
    .heading2 {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: medium;
        font-style: italic;
        color: midnightblue;
    }

    #customAlert {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px medium #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        z-index: 1000;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #overlay {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        z-index: 999;
    }

    #alertSymbol {
        font-size: 36px;
        color: #FF6347; /* Coral color, you can change this */
    }

    #alertMessage {
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #333;
    }

    #closeButton {
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #007BFF; 
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Script method:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showCustomAlert() {
        var customAlert = document.getElementById('customAlert');
        var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

        customAlert.style.display = 'block';
        overlay.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hideCustomAlert() {
        var customAlert = document.getElementById('customAlert');
        var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

        customAlert.style.display = 'none';
        overlay.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Action PopupMessge

```
 <div class="pos-rel">
     <div id="customAlert">
         <div id="alertSymbol">&#9888;</div>
         <!-- Unicode character for warning symbol -->
         <div id="alertMessage">
             <asp:Label ID="alertMessageM" runat="server" Text="Message" CssClass="heading2"></asp:Label>
         </div>
         <button id="closeButton" onclick="hideCustomAlert()">Close</button>
     </div>

     <div id="overlay"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Message box to show success message. This works great for me.

`MessageBox.Show("Data inserted successfully");`

Comment: Message.Show is not for asp.net

Comment: this is not an answer to the question

Comment: It is not related to the question, but answered my question. Thanks!