# Call Javascript from C# code-behind not work

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've been using the same Page.clientScript to call javascript from code-behind refer to this link [Calling javascript function from Codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731224/calling-javascript-function-from-codebehind) in other project and it's worked, but it's doesn't work now in my current project.

here's my c# code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Page_LoadComplete);
}

void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Page Loaded");

    var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

    if (!namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists(CID, "AllMessages"))
    {
        namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(CID, "AllMessages");
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sub Existed : " + namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists(CID, "AllMessages"));

    client = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, CID, "AllMessages");

    // OnMessageOptions eventDrivenMessagingOptions = new OnMessageOptions();            
    // eventDrivenMessagingOptions.ExceptionReceived += OnExceptionReceived;            

    client.OnMessage(OnMessageArrived);
}

void OnMessageArrived(BrokeredMessage message)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("++++++++++++++++++++");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message.GetBody<UpdateData>().data);
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "MyFunction()", true);
}

static void OnExceptionReceived(object sender, ExceptionReceivedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Thank You.

Comment: What's in the debug log? Is `OnMessageArrived` ever called?

Comment: Message has been called. It write the line "+++++++++++" and the data from the message but it doesn't call the Page.ClientScript

Comment: @user3184474: did you try to add up some alert message in the Javascript function 'MyFunction()' to verify if the problem is in Javascript or with Registering the script.?

Comment: Yes, i did but nothing happened.