# How to call a codebehind function from javascript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to call a function from my code behind using javascript. I used the below code:

```
function fnCheckSelection() {
some script;
window["My"]["Namespace"]["GetPart"](null);
}
```

...where `"GetPart"` is the function name. However, this is not working. Please help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731224/calling-javascript-function-from-codebehind)

Comment: @Aria.I need the viceverse of what you said. I need to call a method in codebehind from javascript.

Comment: @charu did you try my answer ?

Comment: Please have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28829291/896276

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil.  Yes I tried. But i was not able to add namespace for webmethod. So it is not working.

Comment: @charu if you are talking about WebMethod attribute, you find it in `System.Web.Services` namespace

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil I tried adding that.But it showed error on [webmethod]

Comment: @charu What's this error or Exception ?? And it's [WebMethod] . it is case sensitive

Comment: did you find any solution for this? or you still need a help?if you need help then let me know

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV No, I dint find a perfect solution till now. As i said in the previous comments, it works fine with button click. But it goes in round trip.  I have got an idea to use update panel. But still the same. Can you please help me on this

Comment: Ok you can use ajax for doing the same i can provide an example for that, check with that and let me know if you have still problems

Comment: ok I will try that. Please share me the code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

in JavaScript:

```
    document.getElementById("btnSample").click();
```

Server side control:

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSample" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="" style="display:none;" OnClick="btnSample_Click" />
```

C#

```
    protected void btnSample_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

It is easy way though...

Comment: It will reload as obvious. When you click the server control, ASP.NET always loads the page and then call the event which is triggered from JavaScript call. Its like we are clicking the button without mouse.

Comment: Yeah. But if i use Update Panel, I can update the particular portion right? And my grid which is supposed to update is inside the update panel. But still it is not working. Do you have any idea on this.

Comment: For the javascript code, I believe you need to use document.getElementById('<%=btnSample.ClientID%>').click();

Comment: @Nachiket I want to pass parameters how can i do it?

Comment: or add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to `btnSample`.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this by an ajax call

this is a jquery example:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
     url:"~/code_behind.aspx/Method",
            data: dataPost,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
    ....
    });
```

here is [api](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation
and in code behind

```
[WebMethod]
public static yourType Method (Params){}
```

or you can add a hidden button inside updatePanel, and invoke the click event using js. `('#<%=ID.ClientID%>').click();`
It will invoke the OnClientClick if it exists then your codeBehind fucntion.

Comment: `~/code_behind.aspx/Method` should be resolved with eg `.ResolveClientUrl`

Comment: `~` is no valid qualifier in pure HTML, it does only work for ASP.net and needs resolving according to the applications virtual path, which can be achieved with eg [`.ResolveClientUrl("~/foo.aspx")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx)https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx

Comment: You don't need to resolve anything. Just write: `url: yourpage.aspx/Method` .

Comment: Can I do it without static?

Answer (score 5):

try this

**Your code behind function**

```
[WebMethod]
public  static void GetPart() {

               //your code goes here
}
```

.
       **Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $("#btnname").click(function () {

 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/youraspxpagename.aspx/GetPart",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg)
                    {

                    }
                });
});

});
```

Comment: try this and let me know if you have still problems

Comment: fix a break point in code behind function and check whether it is hitting

Answer (score -1):

Using ajax, you can call a codebehind function from javascript using JQuery:

```
function : fnCheckSelection(){
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "/GetPart"
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {

        },
        error: function (msg) {

        }
    });
}
```