# How to invoke function in asp.net using javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, tablednd

I'm using the jquery plugin tablednd

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mygridview').tableDnD();
})
```

to make my rows in my gridview draggable.
When I've dragged a row I want to invoke a function in asp.net to save the positions of the rows. But I can't find a proper event on gridview that only reacts on clicking on a row.

There is a onDrop method in tableDnd.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mygridview').tableDnD({
      onDrop: function(table, row) {
   });
})
```

But how could I from there invoke a asp.net method? I've read some about ajax post but I don't understand that.

And I also read about using `PageMethods` but it didn't invoke my function.

The question is how can I write something that executes an update on a table in my database?

**UPDATED:**

I solved it using the IPostBackEventHandler method.

I had to extend both my user control and my page with IPostBackEventHandler 
and then added the public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument) function on both the user control and page. And finally:

```
onDrop: function (table, row) {
                __doPostBack('<%= this.UniqueID %>', 'Select');
            }
```

If someone got problem with onDrop, the solution is you have to give ID to each row like this:

```
    var i = 0;
    $("#<%= gridviewID.ClientID %>").find('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('id', i++);
    });
```

above the initiation of the tablednd.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call ASP.NET Function From Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript)

Comment: I'm getting the error: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct on all my classes when adding IPostBackEventHandler{} to my Page class. You know why?

Comment: the problem is with the approach. you *should not* use gridview and ajax updates. if you wanna use`tableDND` you should ideally fill your table using ajax call. because the databind of a gridview is a server side event while updation in tableDnD is a clientside event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways in general, one using AJAX and second, using postbacks.

The AJAX way:

1. Add ScriptManager to the page, like this:

   ```
   <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"
          ID="ScriptManager1" 
          EnablePageMethods="true"
          EnablePartialRendering="true"
   />
   ```
2. Make the server side method to be called as public static. Also mark it with the System.Web.Services.WebMethod attribute, like this:

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   public static string DoServerStuff(string parameter)
   {
       return "Parameter passed: " + parameter;
   }
   ```
3. Call it from the client side, via the PageMethods class, like this:

   ```
   function doClientStuff() {
       var result = PageMethods.DoServerStuff('test parameter');
       alert(result);
   }
   ```
4. For doing the same thing using jQuery check [this](http://brian.dobberteen.com/code/calling-a-pagemethod-with-jquery/) out.

---

The postbacks way:

1. Make the page (that contains the method to be called) implement the IPostBackEventHandler interface.
2. Call the __doPostback method on the client side, like this:

   ```
   function doClientStuff() {
       var result = __doPostBack('<%= this.UniqueID %>', 'Select');
   }
   ```
3. Implement the server side logic inside the IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent method of the page.
4. More on the raising postbacks from the client side [here](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/320_Doing_or_Raising_Postback_using___doPostBack()_function_from_Javascript_in_AspNet.aspx).

Comment: When using the AJAX method: I'm getting the error: `PageMethods is not defined`. When using the postbacks way: I'm getting the error `Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct` on all my classes when adding IPostBackEventHandler{} to my Page class.

Comment: Make sure that: 1. you've specified an Id for the ScriptManager 2. its EnablePageMethods is set to true and 3. your server method is on the PAGE not the User Control

Comment: Ok, then it wont work, the server method is in the user control.

Comment: Yes, it won't, but you can still use the IPostBackEventHandler option ;)

Comment: There's no way to do the logic in the User control aspx.cs where I've my draggable gridview?

Comment: I tried the IPostBackEventHandler option and when I dropped my row the site does a postback but it never executes my "RaisePostBackEvent" function. I've extended my page with IPostBackEventHandler.