# How to run a Code Behind function when jQuery UI slider value changes

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Here's my code:

```
    function display() {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var txtStart = $("#TextBox1");
            var txtStartDate = $(txtStart).val(); //Value from arrival

            var txtEnd = $("#TextBox2");
            var txtEndDate = $(txtEnd).val();
            var minDate = new Date(txtStartDate);
            var maxDate = new Date(txtEndDate);

            $("#slider").slider({
                min: minDate.getTime(),
                max: maxDate.getTime(),
                step: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000, // 1 day
                slide: function (e, ui) {
                    var currentDate = new Date(ui.value);
                    $('#now').text(currentDate.toDateString());
                },

                change: function (e, ui) {

              /*I want to run the code behind function here*/    

                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is not clear what does it mean 'behind function' ? You want to run smth before change?

Comment: code behind means a function in aspx.cs in asp.net

Comment: no i dont want to change something before . i want to run the aspx.cs function when the sliders' current value get changed

Comment: If I'm reading what aspx.cs is correctly, it's server side code.  So you will not be able to call methods directly from the client.  You will have to perform an ajax call.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827196/how-to-call-a-codebehind-function-from-javascript-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute the "code behind" or your Server Side script, you must Post back via AJAX. In your Change Callback, you will want to do something like:

```
change: function(e, ui){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "~/code_behind.aspx/Method",
    data: { date: $('#now').val() },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  });
}
```

Since it's not clear from your post, I cannot clarify further. You will need to adapt this to your scripts and your needs.

Comment: if my code behind page name as "sick.aspx.cs" and the method name is "desease" How the url should be written?

Comment: `sick.aspx/desease` I suspect. I don't do a lot of .NET stuff, sorry.