# JavaScript not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have problem with javascript. I have a master page (Page1.master) and Aspx page (Page2.aspx) when i redirecting from Page1.master to Page2.aspx, my Javascript function not getting triggered.

I have ScriptManager in both master and aspx page
In my master page, i have like this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

In my aspx page, i have UpdatePanel in addition to ScriptManager. 
It looks like

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upp" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
//other controls
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here My javascript function:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
Type cstype = this.GetType();
string csname = "MyScript";
if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(cstype, csname))
{
System.Text.StringBuilder js = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
js.Append("<script language=JavaScript>");
js.Append("function closeWindow() {");
js.Append("if(myWindow == null) {");
js.Append("var myWindow = window.open('', 'myWindow'); }");
js.Append("myWindow.close();");
js.Append("}");
js.Append("</script>");
cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, csname, js.ToString());
}
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "CloseWindowScript", "closeWindow();", true);
```

Can anyone help me to make it work.. 
Thanks

Comment: What javascript function?

Comment: A `ScriptManager` does not trigger javascript spontaneously.

Comment: Where is your JavaScript function ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731224/calling-javascript-function-from-codebehind
Refer to this link @Naveen

Comment: @Pugazh, Updated the javascript in the question

Comment: @DivyeshGauswami Thanks. I have tried that also. But i didn't get the expected result. I guess this is something related to ScriptManager

Comment: @Turnip, Is anything wrong in my code?

Comment: okay, try to do using that link. @Naveen
if you stuck anywhere then plz do comment with tag.

Comment: ScriptManager works fine. It's your javascript that is the problem. Test it outside the stringbuilder on the aspx itself and see if it works. Once you got it working put in on the code behind.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't belong in the code behind in the first place. Keep your JavaScript in the markup and/or in .js files that you reference on the page.