# javascript on web value from c# winform

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms

i hope to data in table to winform datagridview.

here's the working code

```
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="CallOpen.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/w~~~~==" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
```

other aspx

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="ifrmmain" class="mainiframe" scrolling="auto" style="display: inline;" src="/Category/Service/Call/CallOpen.aspx">
#document
<html ~~~>
<head> ~~~ />
<body> 
<form name="form1" meothd="post" action="~~~" id="form1">
<div id="content">
</div>
</form>
</iframe>
```

i just show that iframe data in my winform.

Comment: This will give you the JSON response object. What else do you need?

Comment: @praty, that gives you only the string, but it not in json format.

Comment: i want  execute javascript in c# winfrom if i pressed the button

Comment: Do you have a `webbrowser` running in your `winform` application where you are loading a page with a javascript?

Comment: Please check if this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731224/calling-javascript-function-from-codebehind

Comment: Make no sense you try to run JavaScript in WindowsForms App? If was Webforms or MVC OK.. you can use functions like Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript to do the trick. (but in WEB). Or you can explain more about your scenario..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your application is WinForms right? You want to retrieve an value? From where? Why don't you create an WebAPI or WebService ? Then you can connect via WindowsForms Application and get the values correctly.

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro in my Winforms, execute javascript(web path) and gather data and showing my datagrid

Comment: can you type the webpath that you have here?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Agility Pack can load and parse the file for you, no need for messy streams and responses:

http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex

Example:

c# code:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load("http://localhost/site.html");
        HtmlNode rateNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//iframe[@id='test']");
        string rate = rateNode.InnerText;
    }
```

HTML File with the iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe id="test" src="https://www.w3schools.com">

</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx. i solved. but i have more task.
when i load site it shows plz login. ill search other posts :)
thx