# Call javascript function from server side?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a `asp:customvalidator` that calls the function `test(sender, args)`.
I am using an `UpdatePanel` with `ScriptManager`.

How can I call it from server side?

I have an `asp:customvalidator` associated to a control. The js function check which item is selected from that control and modify the length of a textbox. The problem lies when the user load up that page again but with data. I have to run the previous function to update the new length else the customvalidator will validate the old maxlength.

Comment: If you're using MVC, you might as well run the javascript on page-load. If you're not, you could look into using something like SignalR.

Comment: Im using asp.net webforms. I have created an asp:customvalidator but I also want to execute that function from server side from a method for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling JavaScript Function From CodeBehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731224/calling-javascript-function-from-codebehind)

Comment: All those examples are function without parameters, I need to send (sender, args), the sender should be the control that I want to modify but the event args?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Text", "function()", true);
```

Comment: My function is sending (sender, args). If I call it from a method I created, shouldn't I be sending something to function()?