# How can i triggered the function (javascript) using backend (c#)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a problem I call the function (showpincode()) but the value is not working can you help me. I call it using backend but the value (txtRequestEncrypted.text) did not work

BACKEND C#

```
 List<Upload> c = new List<Upload>();
                c.Add(b);
                a.UploadCardDetails = c;

                a.ProgramName = null;
                a.IPAddress = "111.222.33.444";
                a.Authentication = "Basic RXFNzdzw==";
                object obj = a;
                string test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);


                string pkey = "test";
                string psalt = "test1";
                string Result = Utilities.Utilities.test1(test, pkey, psalt);

                txtRequestEncrypted.Text = Result.ToString();

this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<script type='text/javascript'>ShowPINPad();</script>"));
```

JAVASCRIPT VALIDATION TO ACCESS THE PINCODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        window.addEventListener("message", function (ev) {
           "https://testtest.com.ph/index"
            //event origin of virtual pin pad
            $origin = ev.origin;
            //event source of virtual pin pad
            $source = ev.source;
            //IMPORTANT: CHECK THE ORIGIN OF THE DATA!
            if (ev.origin.indexOf($sourceURL)) {
                if (ev.data.message === "deliverResult") {
                    ev.source.close();
                }
                else if (ev.data.message == "RESEND") {
                    txtResponse
                    try {

                        setTimeout(function () {
   var requestData = $('#<%= txtRequestEncrypted.ClientID %>').val();

                            child.postMessage({ message: "requestResult", encryptedRequestData: requestData}, "*");
                        }, 3000);
                    } catch (e) {
                        //checking the virtual pin pad is closed
                        if (child.closed) {
                            console.log('Error encountered when calling virtual pinpad...');
                            clearTimeout(interval);
                            //do something
                            document.getElementById("txtResponse").value = "CLOSED";
                            document.getElementById("txtResponseEncrypted").value = "";
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        });
```

THIS IS THE FUNCTION to Show Pinpad

```
 var child = null;

    function ShowPINPad() {
        var height = 406;
        var width = 450;
        var left = Math.round((screen.width / 2) - (width / 2));
        var top = Math.round((screen.height / 2) - (height / 2));
        var targetURL = "https:test.com.ph/index"
        child = window.open(targetURL, "_blank", "scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,directories=no,copyhistory=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",left=" + left + ",top=" + top + ";");
        // child.focus();
    }
```

Comment: The backend and the client code work in completely different environments and most of the time completely different machines. You can't just expect the backend to execute JS code after it has served the page. You have to make the two communicate in some fashion first.

Comment: @VLAZ, I think bossjerk is simply asking how can he call javascript function from asp.net code. So there is a way to call it. Although, there are other posts already giving answers to it

Comment: Hi sir Vlaz 
But i already get the value to access the website but  the problem i got is the showpincode site did not pop up!

Comment: Hi Khurram ishaque sir i can i call the function (showpincode) using backend. c#

Answer (score 0):

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","MyFunction()",true);

check more Details On This Link

[Calling JavaScript Function From CodeBehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731224/calling-javascript-function-from-codebehind)

Comment: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "ShowPINPad()", true); 

idont get it the "CallmyFunction"

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below code to call javascript function from code behind:

```
string jquery = "drawImage();"
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "a key", 
 "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"+ jquery +"</script>"
           );
```

For more details: 
[Call javascript function from code behind](https://codepedia.info/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind-server-side-asp-net-c/)

Comment: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "ShowPINPad()", true);

I dont get it the second paramater i pass "CallMyFunction"

Comment: 2nd parameter is just any unique name you may assign it

Comment: thank you sir i call it but the value i pass in  showpincode is null hayss!

Comment: Can you please mention some code, how the value (parameter) is passed. In your question no value is passed