# how to call function in code behind with javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, button, onclick

i want to call the function located in the code behind from javascript

Button :

```
<button class = "btn btn-outline btn-danger dim" type = "button" onclick = "confirmDelete ()"> <i class = "fa fa-trash"> </i> Delete </button>
```

Javascript function :

```
<script>
     function confirmDelete () {
         if (confirm ('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
             // call function Delete_Click ();
         }
         return false; // cancel the click event always
     }
 </script>
```

the function I want to call:

```
protected void Delete_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         try
         {
             Delete item
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             SetError (ex.Message);
         }
     }
```

if I use <asp: Button> or <asp: LinkButton>, there are some css don't show up.
That's why I use

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731224/calling-javascript-function-from-codebehind

Comment: Could you provide an example in codepen or something similar so that we have a working example that we can take a closer look at?

Answer (score 0):

First change you button and add `runat`,`Id`,`OnClientClick` and `OnClick` event :

```
   <button Id="MyBtn" runat="server" 
    class = "btn btn-outline btn-danger dim" type ="button" 
    OnClientClick="return confirmDelete()" 
    OnClick="Delete_Click"> 
      <i class = "fa fa-trash"> </i> Delete 
    </button>
```

And change you js function :

```
 function confirmDelete () {
     return confirm ('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
 }
```