# Which is faster RegisterStartupScript or RegisterClientScriptBlock?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I saw Difference between `RegisterStartupScript` and `RegisterClientScriptBlock` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666519/difference-between-registerstartupscript-and-registerclientscriptblock).
There is describing the injection javascript code from Sever side using both of them.
Now I am also  injecting client side script from an ASP.NET Server Control but my client script is just pointing to an external JavaScript file.

```
string jsString="<script src="myscripts.js"></script>"
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "JSScriptBlock",jsString);
```

I am using `RegisterClientScriptBlock`,but I want to know should I use `RegisterStartupScript` to be faster.
Which is faster `RegisterStartupScript` or `RegisterClientScriptBlock` in my case?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you experience speed issues with any of them? If not, why would you worry about speed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`The RegisterClientScriptBlock` method inserts the client-side script immediately `below the opening tag of the Page object's element`. The code cannot access any of the form's elements because, at that time, the elements haven't been instantiated yet.

The `RegisterStartupScript` method inserts the specified client-side script just `before the closing tag of the Page object's element`. The code can access any of the form's elements because, at that time, the elements have been instantiated.

The choice of which method to use really depends on the "order" in which you want your script to be run by the browser when rendering the page.