# Open simple JQM dialog from codebehind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I'm using the dialog script for JQM 1.0 below.
It Works fine, but I want to open it from asp.net codebehind
on page_load. How could I accomplish that?

Something like, but I can't make it work:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "open", "opendialog", True)

// The JS:

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).delegate('#opendialog', 'click', function () {

$('<div>').simpledialog2({
          mode: 'blank',
          headerText: 'Some Stuff',
          headerClose: true,
          blankContent:
"<ul data-role='listview'><li>Some</li><li>List</li><li>Items</li></ul>" +
"<a rel='close' data-role='button' href='#'>Close</a>" 
})
})

</script>  
<a href="#" id="opendialog" data-role="button">Open Dialog</a>
```

Comment: I don't get your selector. `$('<div>')`?

Comment: Hi, it's a pop-up example in it's most simple

Comment: format. Please look at the example here: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/popup.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the JavaScript in your example is already in the HTML, in your code behind just use 
RegisterStartupScript (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx) to fire the button click:

```
  Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
  sb.Append("<script>")
  sb.Append("$('#opendialog').click();")
  sb.Append("</script>")

  If (Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("open")) Then
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "open", sb.ToString())
  End If
```

Here is a discussion onRegisterStartupScript vs RegisterClientScriptBlock: [Difference between RegisterStartupScript and RegisterClientScriptBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666519/difference-between-registerstartupscript-and-registerclientscriptblock)

Comment: Hi - thank you for your suggestion, but I still have to push the button before the pop-up shows, even though I place the script inside my body html. I found the original code sample here: dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/popup.html

Comment: It should fire the click event automatically. Try replacing sb.Append("$('#opendialog').click();") with sb.Append("alert('from server')") and see if the alert box shows up.