# Unable to run Javascript function along with asp.net function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a asp.net button

I want to run a JavaScript function `animation()` along with the asp.net function `Button1_Click` when the user clicks on `submit`.

i have written the following code for the same but unable to get the desired result

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "animation()");
    <Some Code Here>
     }
```

Comment: Not sure if it matters but it should be lowercase letters on the attribute key.

Comment: try it bysetting onclientclick attribute

Comment: Use `OnClientClick` to have your ASP.NET button run a JavaScript method before calling its server-side method. `OnClick` specifies the server side method to run.

Comment: "onclientclick" is not working, gives an error "Cannot find function"

Comment: try using `Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:animation()");`

Answer (score 1):

You must include your code outside of the click definition. you can include it on page_load event as..

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
             Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "animation()");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a script manager to run your javascript functions from server side:
1) You must add a script manager to your page 
eg: 
`<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnablePageMethods="true" AsyncPostBackTimeout="600" />`

2) on your _Click function

`protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string script = "$(function(){animation();});";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script, true);
}`

there are two methods you may use with ScriptManager: 
- RegisterStartupScript
- RegisterClientScriptBlock
**[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666519/difference-between-registerstartupscript-and-registerclientscriptblock)** is a post that tells the difference between them

Answer (score 0):

You can add the javascript function on `OnClientClick` attribute of the `Button`.

like

`<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="animation();" OnClick="Button1_Click" />`