# Open another asp.net page in a different tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a button on click event, and I want when the user click it to open another page but from the same problem.

I tried this

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('http://www.google.com.hk/','_blank');</script>");
```

but the problem is that it opens the page **not in a new tab**

How can I open it in a new tab?

Comment: If you find yourself using `Response.Write` to inject code or markup into a webpage, you're doing it wrong. There's always a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "key", "window.open('http://www.google.com.hk/','_blank');", true);
```

Comment: now it is working, but i am looking for some solution in which i just put the name of the page, without the full url, because i don't know on which port the customer will deploy this app on. can u help please

Comment: But it will be mapped to some domain ?

Comment: i changed your code to this `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "key", "window.open('EmailTemplate.aspx?emailAddress="+emailAddress+"','_blank');", true);` and it is working now, but do you think this is correct? plus one and I will accept your answer when the system allows

Comment: What do you mean by Is this correct i am not getting you ?

Comment: is that the best way to do it?

Comment: Yes it is most commonly used method.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use `RegisterStartupScript` instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock`.

Given below is the way to use `RegisterStartupScript`. You should use it in your case.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "ReportPage", "javascript:window.open('EmailTemplate.aspx?emailAddress="+emailAddress+"','_blank');", true);
```

---

Because when you use `RegisterStartupScript`, it will render your script after all the elements in the page (right before the form's end tag). This enables the script to call or reference page elements without the possibility of it not finding them in the Page's DOM.

On the other hand when you use `RegisterClientScriptBlock`, the script is rendered right after the `Viewstate` tag, but before any of the page elements. Since this is a direct script (not a function that can be called, it will immediately be executed by the browser. But the browser does not find the label in the Page's DOM at this stage and hence you should receive an "Object not found" error.

For further details visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666519/difference-between-registerstartupscript-and-registerclientscriptblock/666560#666560) answer.