# How to call Javascript function from server side asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a `Textbox` in `GridView` I want to change the Label.Text if the text in Textbox is changed. But I am not able call javascript function written in .cs page. Is there any mistake in `TbUnitCost_TextChanged` method.

This is my aspx page

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox Style="text-align: right" ID="TbUnitCost" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%#Bind("Unit_Cost")%>' AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TbUnitCost_TextChanged"  TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Code behind Page is as follows

```
 protected void TbUnitCost_TextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow currentRow = (GridViewRow)((TextBox)sender).Parent.Parent;
        int rowNo = currentRow.RowIndex;
        string gridName = "GridWorkExpenses";
        TextBox tbunitCost = (TextBox)currentRow.FindControl("TbUnitCost");
        int row = Convert.ToInt32(tbunitCost.Text);

        tbunitCost.Attributes.Add("onchange","javascript:calculateTotalCost('"+rowNo+"','"+gridName+"');");

    }
```

and javascript Function is:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    function calculateTotalCost(rowNo, GridName) {                        

        if (GridName== 'GridWorkExpenses') {
            var rowscount = document.getElementById('<%=GridWorkExpensesSheet.ClientID%>').rows.length;
            return calculateTotalUnitCost("GridWorkExpensesSheet", rowscount,rowNo);
        }
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: Not clear.. What exactly you want to achieve? do you want to change it from client side or server side? You have set AutoPostBack="true" , that means page will be submitted to server , I guess on events like OnItemDataBound you can attach the javascript call, make AutoPostBack="false"

Comment: Can't I call javascript function using Textbox.Attributes.Add() method?

Comment: Why are you calling it from server side? You can do it on Js onchange event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Script", "CalculateTotalCost", true);
```

Describe any further problem (if there is any).

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Script", "<script type='text/javascript'>CalculateTotalCost</script>", false);
```

is another method

This is a very old discussion [1]:[Difference between RegisterStartupScript and RegisterClientScriptBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666519/difference-between-registerstartupscript-and-registerclientscriptblock)

Please refer this too.

Answer (score 0):

hi you must write all of command in the one string

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((sender as Control), GetType(), "jQueryCommand", "$('.MenuLoginLink').hide();$('.MenuUsername').show();$('.MenuUsername').text('" + Currentmember.Mobile  + "');$('.MenuExit').show();" +
                " $('.btnLoginInFriends').hide();$('#HiddenSession').val('" + int.Parse(Session["CurrentUserID"].ToString()) + "');", true);
```