# Kentico 7 create content placeholder in Portal Master to use in ASCX in inherited page

Tags: ascx, kentico

Working in Kentico 7 on an Ad-Hoc page that inherits from Portal Master. I want to insert some literal script or code right before the `</body>` tag in the rendered ad-hoc page.

I thought I'd have to do this by editing the portal master and adding the following:

```
<cms:CMSPagePlaceholder ID="plcBodyEnd" runat="server">
   <LayoutTemplate>
   </LayoutTemplate>
</cms:CMSPagePlaceholder>
```

and then in the layout of the Ad-Hoc page do this:

```
<cms:CMSContent runat="server" id="cntLeft" PagePlaceholderID="plcBodyEnd">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
ProviderConnections.Transparency.initializeWidget({ }); 
</script> 
</cms:CMSContent>
```

This worked fine until I went to the design tab on the Ad-Hoc page, where I got the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I don't want to register script blocks. I just want to put text in the Ad-Hoc page that goes there before the `</body>` tag, which is controlled by Portal Master.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve. Giving an example or attaching a screenshot would be very helpful.

Here are the ways of attaching JavaScript in Kentico:

**Through portal engine:**

- Use JavaScript web part - that gives you an option of choosing where the script should be located

[image: JavaScript web part]

**Programmatically from code-behind:**

- Use `CMS.Helpers.ScriptHelper` API (wrapper around ASP.NET's `ClientScriptManager`)

  - `ScriptHelper.RegisterStartupScript()` to put the script at the end of the page
  - `ScriptHelper.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` to put the script before page's elements
- The difference between the two is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666519/difference-between-registerstartupscript-and-registerclientscriptblock).

**Programmatically from ASPX markup:**

- Put your `<script>` block to a desired location in your .aspx / .ascx files
- Evaluate a code-behind variable containing script

  `<asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
      <%= fieldWithActualScript %>
  </script>`

Comment: What if I want a simple placeholder? Literal control. Something I can render before </body> and put script or other things in there.

Comment: The startup script is what you want - it renders just before form's closing tag (which renders just before body's closing tag).