# How to register ClientScript at the very bottom of the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` to generate script tag on page.
But This will place my script at the top of the page.  I want this execute after everything else on the page as the very last line in the html.
How do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between RegisterStartupScript and RegisterClientScriptBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666519/difference-between-registerstartupscript-and-registerclientscriptblock)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use this `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` instead.