# I need help inserting code to the end of the ASP.NET page with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to make the following to work with no luck

```
string MY_SCRIPT_CODE = "<script>";
MY_SCRIPT_CODE += " document.getElementById('rq1').addEventListener('click', function () {";
MY_SCRIPT_CODE += "     document.getElementById('myBtn').click();";
MY_SCRIPT_CODE += "  });";
MY_SCRIPT_CODE += "</script>"; 
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl bodyTag = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl();
bodyTag = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)(Page.FindControl("</body>"));
bodyTag.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(MY_SCRIPT_CODE));

<!-- Final Result should placed after the HTML Tag </body> --> 
<!-- and before the HTML Tag </html> after insertion -->
</body>
    <!-- Insertion from the C# Code  --->
    <script>
          document.getElementById("rq1").addEventListener('click', function () {
              document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
          });
    </script>
</html>
```

Is the above mentioned possible?

TIA

Comment: Well you're adding the script in a very strange way and obviously you're adding it to `bodyTag`, so I don't know why you think it would appear after the body tag. Any reason why you aren't using [RegisterStartupScript or RegisterClientScriptBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666519/difference-between-registerstartupscript-and-registerclientscriptblock)? That is how you'd normally do it with web forms.

Comment: Dear Jose, can you please interact in any way? Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is a very interesting requirement.

Normally, we add a script to a page by using:

```
RegisterClientScriptBlock("myScript", MY_SCRIPT_CODE);
```

And let Asp.Net handle where to put it.

And normally, we don't try to put a script to attach to an event listener "after the `</body>` closing tag" to make sure it executes after the page is loaded, but do: (using jquery, just as an example)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rq1").on('click', function() { $("#myBtn").trigger('click'); });
}
```

But ok, thinking that you have this specific assignment (like rendering the exact HTML output as-is from an earlier project), here is a BAD BAD BAD hack which should do the trick.

the significant class `Control` (from which all web controls extend) gives us the possibility to completely override the rendering of the control by assigning a delegate function using `SetRenderMethodDelegate()`.

What we do is, we first set it for `theBody` (our actual body) to have our delegate method invoked,

And when we are actually invoked, we hack into Control and erase it and Render the `<body>`as usual and then render our script.

Here is the implementation:

First, give your `<body>` and id and set runat="Server" to access it from the code behind:

```
ASPX:

<body runat="server" id="theBody">
```

Then, implement this in your code behind:

```
ASPX.CS:

private void RenderMyScript(HtmlTextWriter output, Control container)
{
    object controlRareFields = typeof(Control)
        .GetProperty("RareFieldsEnsured", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .GetValue(theBody, null);

    controlRareFields.GetType().GetField("RenderMethod").SetValue(controlRareFields, null);

    theBody.RenderControl(output);

    output.Write(MY_SCRIPT_CODE);
}
```

And finally, override OnPreRenderComplete and set our delegate:

```
protected override void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRenderComplete(e);
    theBody.SetRenderMethodDelegate(RenderMyScript);
}
```

And that's all.

Here are the last few lines my page output:

```
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>

<script>
     document.getElementById('rq1').addEventListener('click', function () {;
         document.getElementById('myBtn').click();
     });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Oguz for your reply, I like it, I think that should work by placing the body tag to runat as server side then rendering the script. Thank you much for your reply and help.