# jQuery $(document).ready? and UpdatePanels - some issues

Tags: jquery, updatepanel

I have referenced this existing query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels) regarding jQuery $(document).ready? and UpdatePanels

I am getting a Javascript error on line...

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
```

The error is :

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys'
> is undefined

Any resolution for this? What could I be missing?

Answer (score 2):

Taking this a step further from what Paperjam wrote.

```
var prm;

$(document).ready(function(){
    prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
});
```

That will avoid trying to reference Sys before it exists. If that doesn't work it could be something else entirely.

Comment: You'll probably need to do something like this also, to prevent $ clash between ASP.NET Ajax and jQeury

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ASP.NET ScriptManager control is above your Javascript. It could very easily be that you're calling `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager` before it's been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your page contains the following:

```
<asp:scriptmanager runat="server" />
```