# Update panel used in conjuction with jquery tree

Tags: asp.net, jquery, updatepanel

i have a page which is basically just a big unordered list - sort of navigation really - and its in a nasty frame (nothing i can do about that at the mo.. but i digress)

i need to reload this page/frame as items are added/removed/reordered 
but i would really like it to do it via an update panel, so it doesnt (visually) have to reload the page.

unfortunately when i do drop it all in an update panel when it reloads, it doesnt re-run the jquery tree script to restyle etc itself 
even if i put the jquery bit inside the update panel itself..

is there any function/event .. something that i can use to retrigger the treeview functionality?

at the mo its just in a 
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("ul.nav").treeview({ animated: "medium" });
    });

what i really need it to do (if this is yet unclear) is to when the update panel has finished 'loading' for it to re-treeview itself

something like

$(document).hasbeenreloadedviaupdatepanel(function(){
  $("ul.nav").treeview({ animated: "medium" });
});

dotn really want to have to generate it from xml using the jstree thing, which i am vaguely familiar with..

any ideas?

thanks

nat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this SO Question:

[jQuery $(document).ready and UpdatePanels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels)