# jquery with updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

Why jquery tool when placed in an updatepanel do not work?
Jquery calender I've written, if it were inside a updatepanel do the work falls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript events in UpdatePanels are unbound when the panel posts back.

See this question for more details: [jQuery $(document).ready and UpdatePanels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels)

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced the same problem.I used update panel just only to stop the whole page refresh in asp.net which even included the jquery.But after using the update panel somewhat the problem was solved but created another problem. jquery script was not working inside the updatepanel.
For further details visit the site u may get an idea:

http://kopila.com.np