# Jquery+Updatepanel+UserControl document.ready doesnot get fired

Tags: jquery, updatepanel

I have put some Jquery code in a **user control** and it is placed in a page with updatepanel.

On a button click on a page User Control Grid is displayed.

document.ready event doesn't get fired in **user control** after partial post back.

How do I handle it?

I am following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels) but didn't get solution to my problem.

Comment: That link is the way you hook into the "UpdatePanel finished" event...what isn't it doing correctly?  What are you trying to do after the partial postback?

Comment: After partial postback user control get rendered(displays records in UC grid).I have put a alert in document.ready in UC but it never shows.

Answer (score 0):

Call jquery code after partial postback:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
        // add your functions here
    }
}
```