# JQueryUI and ASP.NET UpdatePanel dispute? Is there any quick alternative?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, updatepanel

I have been using asp.net programming just from few months and I have to maintain an application that is made up of many aspx webforms with updatepanels.

One of the task of the maintenance is to integrate some of the JQueryUI widgets (mostly datepicker, tabs and buttons).

I am experiencing some problems on doing this smoothly expecially when the controls are

1. Inside an update panel
2. Generally inside any templated control (e.g. Wizard control)

For example this very simple code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
 $("#myTabs").tabs();

 $("[ID$=TextBox2]").datepicker();
 $("[ID$=btnOk]").button();

});
</script>

<div>
    Jquery UI controls inside a div (Tabs, datepicker and buttons)
    <br />
    <div id="myTabs">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#myTabs-1">quick sample</a></li>
     </ul>
     <div id="p-tabs-1">
         <p>In this page there are a datepicker control and a button</p>
         <p>
         Please select a date :<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <br />
         <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" OnClientClick="btnOk_Click" />
         </p>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

will immediately cease to work if placed inside an update panel.

Do there is a solution regarding this issue or I have to follow a completely differnt approach? Do I have to substitute all the updatepanels? And what is the best alternative to this easy to use control?

Thanks very much
Lorenzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After applying Chuck suggestion I was getting a javascript error (Sys is not defined).
Googling around tooked me at this web [post](http://encosia.com/2007/08/16/updated-your-webconfig-but-sys-is-still-undefined/) that solved my problem.
Now everything works! :)

Answer (score 0):

See: [jQuery $(document).ready and UpdatePanels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels)

An updatepanel destroys all javascript references, which includes jquery bindings. If it did not do this it would create a memory leak.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your suggestion. I have tried to implement it in the sample but it does not work either. Basically i have created a javascript function (BindJQuery()) where I moved the code that was previous in the $(document).ready function.
I have then called this function either in document.ready as well as in the add_endRequest handler. Is this a wrong method?

Comment: No. The code is as I have posted. I omitted the master page that has only one contentplaceholder.

Comment: @ Chuck what to do if i have nested update panels please suggest me i am in the similar problem

Comment: @Devjosh the update panel kills all javascript references within the update panel. You'll need to re register all the events/plugins.

Comment: @Chuck Conway thanks i used javacript end request handler to refer the javascript again but it is still not working but when there is full post back jquery ui tab and dialog works fine