# Javascript event subscription after UpdatePanel async postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asynchronous, maskedtextbox

I Have a problem with jquery event handler after async postback on asp.net page.
I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels) - it's a good solution, but I need a separate function. 
So I'm using [jquery masked plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

My js code now is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var control = $("#txtCustomerPhone");

  InitPhonePattern(this, control);

  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
  prm.add_endRequest(InitPhonePattern(this, control));
 });

 function InitPhonePattern(sender, args) {
  $(args[0]).mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99", { completed: 
    function () {
    $('#btnCheckCustomerPhone').click();} 
  });

}
</script>
```

As you see mask was initialized 2 times: on document Ready() and after async postback (on endRequest()). But mask plugin is not mapped after async postback.

Someone understands problem? I would be grateful for help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I want so say thanks to [Aristos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159270/aristos) for help and right direction!
In your code I fixed only this string:

```
jQuery(document).ready(Init);//direct transfer function not work;
```

So final code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
     prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

     function EndRequest(sender, args) {
         Init();
     }

     $(document).ready(function () {
         Init();
     });

     function Init() {
         var control = $('#txtCustomerPhone');
         InitPhonePattern(control);
     }

     function InitPhonePattern(args) {
         $(args).mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99", { completed:
            function () {
                $('#btnCheckCustomerPhone').click();
            }
         });
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem in your code is that the jQuery(document).ready is not run after the update panel, so you need to make your endRequest out of jQuery.

Try this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
        prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

        function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      
        }

        function EndRequest(sender, args) {
             Init();
        }

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){Init();});

        function Init()
        {
          var control = $("#txtCustomerPhone");
          InitPhonePattern(control);        
        }

        function InitPhonePattern(args) {
            $(args[0]).mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99", { completed: 
            function () {
               $('#btnCheckCustomerPhone').click();} 
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Aristos, thank you - but now I have following client error: "Sys is not defined"

Comment: oops, for using Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager above it must be placed ScriptManager - I fixed code in my question