# how to make a a javascript callback for AsyncPostBackTrigger in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a custom user control `CustomControl.ascx` with some javascript features declared in `$.fn.CustomControl`. When I use the control, I also init the javascript object by calling `$('#element').CustomControl();`

Now I have this control in an UpdatePanel, and it is my async postback trigger control. After I got my postback, the initialized javascript object is gone, and thus all my javascript event bindings are gone.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188050/javascript-event-subscription-after-updatepanel-async-postback

Comment: @user3638443 ``Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()`` works!