# re-attaching jQuery functionality within UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a problem and possible solution but I'd appreciate a little help with using it.

I have a ASP.NET Timer and when it Ticks I call asynchronously web service method that returns me a photo. I have a image in Update Panel and update it src when I get a photo. I'm using a jQuery lightBox plugin to preview a image. The mechanism works but on a partial postbacks image loses attatched plugin. So I need re-attaching functionality to elements within UpdatePanels.

Possible solution is using ASP.NET AJAX’s pageLoad() to re-attach (http://encosia.com/simplify-aspnet-ajax-client-side-page-initialization/)

I attach plugin with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#gallery a').lightBox({ fixedNavigation: true });
});
</script>
```

As it is said pageLoad() should solve the problem, but how to modify this js to use pageLoad ?

1)How sholud look my js script ? I'm a begginer with js so please help me.

2)Moreover, should I attach sth to my project to use pageLoad() ?

Thanks in advance for Your help.

Comment: you might find this useful, the Livequery plugin.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of question [http://stackoverflow.com/q/256195/464738](http://stackoverflow.com/q/256195/464738).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery, you may want to use its [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) functions which allow you to bind event handlers to current and future elements that match a selector.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will try it if pageLoad() doesn't help. But any ideas how to modify my js call with pageLoad() ?

Comment: Well according to the page you linked to simply declaring a javascript function named `pageLoad()` should suffice. Add whatever you need to do to that function.