# asp checkbox not firing jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Ok I have checked several solution and have no luck. What the heck am I doing wrong. I can retrieve the ID from check_controls doing an alert onload but not on change

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAutoReverse" runat="server" CssClass="" Width="200px" 
     Text="Auto Reverse:" TextAlign="Right" AutoPostBack="false" />

$(document).ready(function() {
    var check_controls = $('input[id*=chkAutoReverse]');
    var AutoReverseOptions = document.getElementById('AutoReverseOptions');

    $(check_controls).change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert($(check_controls).attr("id"));

        } else {
            alert($(AutoReverseOptions).attr("id"));
        }
    });
});
```

additional html markup

```
                            <div style="height: 60px">
                            <div class="singlepanelcontentleft">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAutoReverse" runat="server" CssClass="" Width="200px" Text="Auto Reverse:"
                                    TextAlign="Right" AutoPostBack="false" /></div>
                            <div id="AutoReverseOptions" class="singlepanelcontentleft" style="display: none;">
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="optTabs" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table"
                                    Width="91%" Height="22px">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Next Period" Value="1" Selected="true"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2 Periods from Now" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="3 Periods from Now" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

this is nested in other divs and a fieldset. Pasting the other code did not render well

Comment: I created a demo page with your code, it works fine for me.  What does the rest of your markup look like?

Comment: @Rick, I updated the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the answer. You can get the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels). It boiled down the the controls being in an update panel and not resubscribing to the jQuery events when the panel loaded.

Answer (score 1):

you should reference asp.net IDs using the following:

```
<%= chkAutoReverse.ClientID %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either reference the `ClientID` or set the `ClientIDMode`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Listening to checkboxes works better with a click event than a change event.

---

Attribute selectors need to be enclosed in quotes:

```
var check_controls = $('input[id*="chkAutoReverse"]');
```