# Ajax removes any changes made my javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

Using ajax I am causing an `OnTextChangedEvent` before this happens there is some Javascript that performs a check on the input field for validation and outputs some text based on whether it is valid or not. The Ajax I run resets the changes made by my javascript. It all happens in this order:

**Javascript fires!**

Text changes show

**Ajax fires!**

Text changes reset

The ajax partial autopostback is contained in an update panel. Without giving any code away is there anyone who has an idea of a way to stop the javascript changes resetting?

Over the day I will add code as I find time. Thought I would get the question up atleast. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Which control you are use to show validation result text?

Comment: have you tried my solution? it fires!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Text changes are made in the DOM-Model and are not transmitted to the server.
If the ajax fires it will override the changes in the DOM made by javascript.

Solution is to transmit the validation-texts to the server and to add them again via ajax.

Comment: Your solution works. But I ended up pushing all Ajax changes to jscript, took slightly longer but felt like it was better practice for what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

> An **UpdatePanel completely replaces the contents of the update panel on
>   an update**.
>   This means that those events you subscribed to are no
>   longer subscribed because there are new elements in that update panel.
>   Full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels/256253#256253)

In your Page or MasterPage, put the following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);

  function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
  {
    Validate(); //method that performs check on input field
  }   
</script>
```

Comment: yeah sorry buddy, didn't seem to work for me :(. when I get a moment later today or this week I will give it another shot :).