# After postback my JavaScript function doesn't work in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, postback

I have common functions and I collapse it on `CommonFunctions.js` in Scripts folder.

I include it on my master page and use it on my pages. When I do any post back on a page, my function doesn't work.

My `CommonFunctions.js`:

```
$(function () {

    gf();
    
   if (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
        
        gf();
    }


 function gf(){

    $('.AddNewGeneralPanel').click(function () {

        if ($(this).find('.AddNewGeneralPanelStyle').text() == "") {
            $(this).find('.AddNewGeneralPanelStyle').text("(  Gizle  )");
            lastOpenId = $(this).attr("codeid");
        }
        else
            $(this).find('.AddNewGeneralPanelStyle').text("");

        $(this).next('.AddNewGeneralAccordionDiv').slideToggle('slow', function () {

        });

    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you doing partial postback? I mean update panel with Conditional postback?

Comment: Just to confirm: is this EXACTLY the code you're using? I see a call to a "gf" function but a "gF" function is declared. Don't forget JS is case-sensitive

Comment: yes i use update panel.it works with postback well when i use this javascript codes using <script>...<\script> on a page.But using a .js it doesnt working

Comment: sorry i write it manualy in there.edited it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you're using an `UpdatePanel`, the part of the DOM that you've attached your event handler to is getting dropped and recreated after the postback. This has the effect of removing any event handlers that were attached by jQuery when the page first loaded.

When you postback only part of the page, the jQuery `$(function() {});` doesn't fire again, so your handlers never get reattached.

Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels) that shows how to resubscribe your events when the `UpdatePanel` refreshes.

Comment: I added a link that should help you work out how to resubscribe your function.

Comment: Thank you @JoshEarl
and thank you Mennan for this question.
It really help me.

Answer (score 29):

It is because of updatepanel partial postbacks. here is what you need to do.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
  $(document).ready(function(){   

   // put all your javascript functions here 

  });
}
```

I had the same issue and it worked for me. I hope it helps you too.

Comment: this code works on same page but i called it in masterpage.i try it but dont work for me

Comment: do you have scriptmanager tag in master page? if not put it there and try again.

Comment: i solved this problem thx [postback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels)

Answer (score 8):

It is because of `updatepannel` used. Following code is working fine. Just put your `jquery` code inside the `pageLoad` event like below

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
     $(document).ready(function () {....}
}
```

Comment: The one function that was needed. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 4):

i have the same problem, i have solved with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad()
    {
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();           
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Faced same problem. Change

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

to

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function() {
```

this will force it to run even on partial postbacck

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using an UpdatePanel to do the postback and the JS code is attatched to HTML elements within the update panel you need to attach them again when the update panel is loaded. You can hook up your code on the endRequest event:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx

Keep in mind that if you are using more than one update panel you should check which update panel is refreshed and attach only the events that are needed otherwise you risk events firing more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I had an interesting situation and figured I'd post my solution here in case it helped anyone in the future.

My problem was my OnClick events were firing on initial page load, but not after postback. My second problem was my OnClick fired once on initial page load, then more and more as postbacks went by.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  // function that adds my various OnClick events
  function AddOnClicks() {
    $('.myClass').off("click.highlight"); // .off added so the event doesn't fire multiple times after postbacks
    $('.myClass').on("click.highlight", function () { // note: ".highlight" is just naming the event
        // ... on click logic
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    AddOnClicks(); // this works for initial page load only

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
        AddOnClicks(); // this works after postback         
    });
  });
</script>
```

Why I needed to re-add the event on postback but also remove the previous one is beyond me. Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score -1):

you can put all your JavaScript code in between following code.

function pageLoad(sender, args) {

}