# Function not working after updatepanel triggered

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have this function on the same asp.net page that makes use of UpdatePanels

```
$(function() {
    $("#listTimeInput").change(function() {
        ToggleDropdown();
    });
    ToggleDropdown();
});

function ToggleDropdown() {
    if ($("#listTimeInput").val() == "1") {
        $("#dateBox").show();
    } else {
        $("#dateBox").hide();
    }
};
```

This function works fine when the page is loaded, however after the UpdatePanel is triggered the function no longer works.

I am very new to JavaScript and am not sure if I need to wrap this code into the document.ready statement. I'm also not sure where that would go.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Java` !== `JavaScript`

Comment: Show your aspx code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following approach..

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
  $(document).ready(function(){   

   // put all your javascript functions here 

  });
}
```

or referred to link

[After postback my JavaScript function doesn't work in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719078/after-postback-my-javascript-function-doesnt-work-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

Try calling it in the ajax pageLoad method.

e.g.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
   your code
}
```

btw it's Javascript not Java :)

Comment: Thank you for the input and heads up on the difference.