# Duplicate code in $(document).ready() and prm.add_endRequest()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

**edit:**
after i update the latest code and now i see there are two "characters count" instead of showing only one.
does it mean its executing twice the same code? document.ready and add_endrequest?

```
  $('[id*="txtNewComments"]').charCount({
            allowed: 300,
            warning: 15,
            counterText: 'Characters left: '
        });
```

i am using asp.net page with updatepanel and some jquery when i start using updatepanel my jquery and javascript function stop working and i dont see any action ... after i searched i found this: [jQuery $(document).ready and UpdatePanels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels) link which is very informative but i have a question.

below is the code that does not work if i have a updatepanel...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('[id*="txtNewComments"]').charCount({
            allowed: 300,
            warning: 15,
            counterText: 'Characters left: '
        });

     ..........
     ..........
});

//update:

function UpdateEmployee(....) {}
```

so if i go ahead with the recommended way then i have to have two set of each script one is within the docuement.ready and other set of script is with in the `endRequest` some thing like **this below is working with update panel** if i follow this pattern.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind your jQuery events here initially
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function() {
    // re-bind your jQuery events here
});
```

my question is: is there a way to have one set of script rather then one in document.ready and another in endrequest ?... its a pain to maintain two set of scripts.

any thoughts?

**update with update panel**

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1" OnItemCommand="OnItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="OnItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="Edit" ImageUrl="~/Images/EditDocument.png" runat="server" CommandName="edit" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="Delete" ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete_black_32x32.png" runat="server"
                                CommandName="delete" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="firstName"><%# Eval("FirstName") %></asp:Label>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="firstNameEditPlaceholder" />
                            <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="firstNameHidden" visible="false" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lastName"><%# Eval("LastName") %></asp:Label>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="lastNameEditPlaceholder" />
                            <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="lastNameHidden" visible="false" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="Delete" ImageUrl="~/Images/112_Plus_Blue_32x32_72.png" runat="server"
                                OnClick="OnAddRecord" />
                        </td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NewFirstName" /></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NewLastName" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, why not replace the `UpdatePanel` with a `$.ajax()` call?

Comment: If you include how you are using your `UpdatePanel`, I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: How are you using the UpdatePanel? That is, why did you choose to use a partial postback over a full page postback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    bindJqueryFeatures();
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function() {
    bindJqueryFeatures();
});


function bindJqueryFeatures(){
    //bind your jQuery events here initially 
}
```

Now, if you want to change or add some jQuery features just insert code in **bindJqueryFeatures()** function so you don't need to dublicate your code in both methods: **$(document).ready()** and **prm.add_endRequest()**.

Also [it can be usefull](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Is that what you need?