# CSS are not updating in update panel

Tags: jquery, ajax, updatepanel

I have link button which is kept in the update panel. When i kept this in the update panel. Hover function called through the Jquery not performing correctly, I could not see hover css appliied. When i removed update panel, it is showing correctly.Following is the jquery applied.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#MainContent_LinkGeneral").hover(
            function () { $(this).addClass("TabGeneralHover"); },
            function () { $(this).removeClass("TabGeneralHover"); }
            );


        });
```

why css are not updated in updatepanel.

Comment: Is #MainContent_LinkGeneral the name with or without the update panel? An update panel is a naming container, are you sure you got the id right?

Comment: Maybe your button added to the page dynamically?

Comment: @Mithrandir has right did you check that id on client side is exacly same that in your function i mean `"#MainContent_LinkGeneral"`?

Comment: @Rajaram you can check that with plugin named `Firebug` in mozilla Firefox browser

Comment: All - #MainContent_LinkGeneral is the id generated for linkbutton in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer over here only. I just put

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// bind your jQuery events here initially
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function() {
// re-bind your jQuery events here
});
```

for maintaning the postback. I put above code after scriptmanager and kept this script between ends of form and body tag.
Please refer thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels)