# jQuery tab control in Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tabcontrol

I have used a tab control in my asp.net pages and whenever I have any event in the corresponding tab like display after dropdown select, the tab page comes out of the main page and display without CSS and Scripts.
Am I am missing something here?
I am unable to share the code but would like to know if I am not reaching something.

Comment: Why you are unable to share code??without reference of your code how could we help you...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer on my own, one must create a div inside the main page which contains the tab controls and then the event fired will run smoothly provided one must have used proper jquery library as well as the css in the same main page.

```
<div class="">
<div id="example">
<ul>
     <li><a href="#tab-1"><span>Data1</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab-2"><span>Data2</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab-3"><span>Data3</span></a></li>
 </ul>
<div id="tab-1">content</div>
<div id="tab-2">content</div>
<div id="tab-3">content</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The corresponding div will contain the content of the page which needs to be displayed on the corresponding tab click.