# ajax calender & autocompleteextender does not works when using modalpopup

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I have created panel exists with one form to add details using formview, I have one button to open popup just above to that formview. In my form I used ajax calender, autocompleteextender for textbox in formview. I used list method to autocompleteextender in .cs code not web service to get values from database. Its working properly, but the problem is when i open main panel then calender, autocompleteextender does not work, but when i open popup in that panel & close that popup calender & autocompleteextender works properly.
I want it to work when i makes main panel visible, how it will be possible in my case?
Please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an update panel issue. Maybe the following will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels

Comment: i have not used updatepanel if i use then it does not works

Comment: Does autocomplete extender's hits web method?

Comment: yes it hits when open & close modalpopup, but it does not hits when i just make visible mail panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set target control id properly and if any issues please add the references once again than you problem will be solved.

Comment: i set target control id to autocompleteextender control, why to add references its working if i open & close modalpopup