# Div doesn't fade out in update panel

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I am using an Update Panel and inside it I have a div in which I show a message when the repeater's Item Command is fired.
The div is visible false in beginning.

```
 <div id="divCommentsMsg" class="form_popup_Msg" visible="false" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblCommentsMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </div>
```

It is made visible on repeater's ItemCommand. To fade it out I use:

```
 $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctrlComments_divCommentsMsg").delay(3000).fadeOut(100);
```

The div becomes visible but doesn't fade out. What should I do ?

**UPDATE**
I am trying it in IE 9

Comment: How are you calling the `fadeOut()` function? From some kind of button click, or when the element is appended?

Comment: Obvious question is, have you got the ID of the DIV correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a perfect solution to my problem at this link:

[jQuery $(document).ready and UpdatePanels?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/256253/1398222)

It was because Update Panel rebinds the jquery objects after every update.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$("#'<%=divCommentsMsg.ClientID %>'").delay(3000).fadeOut(100);
```

Use `ClientID` to get the "real" `id` of the element on the client side.

Alternatively use the Ends with selector:

```
$("[id$='divCommentsMsg']").delay(3000).fadeOut(100);
```

Comment: Sometimes it produces rendering issues and it's better to use `$("#'<%=divCommentsMsg.ClientID %>'").delay(3000).fadeIn(0).fadeOut(100);`

Comment: I also suggest to use `style="display: none;"` instead `visible="false"`

Comment: @adripanico, I don't see the point in `fadeIn` a visible element... why would you do that? if the element is visible it won't do a thing and if it's not, what're you trying to fadeOut...?

Comment: As I said, it's for avoid rendering issues introduced because the use of this jQuery functions.

Comment: I am trying it in IE 9. It says that `delay` is not supported.

Comment: ... sorry but I have to ask... did you include the jQuery libraries?

Comment: @adripanico yes.. I am using jquery 1.4.2 min

Comment: [delay wasn't added to jQuery untill ver. 1.43](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and there was changes on fadeIn and fadeOut in ver. 1.4.3. Just update (https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)

Comment: @adripanico, `delay` is in jQuery **since 1.4**, but you're right about `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, they were introduced in 1.4.3

Answer (score 2):

Get the `ClientID` for the server Controls

```
$("#'<%=divCommentsMsg.ClientID %>'").delay(3000).fadeOut(100);
```

Comment: ? why do you repeat what @gdoron says?

Comment: I am trying it in IE 9. It says that `delay` is not supported.

Comment: The `delay()` method was introduced in 1.4. If you have 1.4 or later `delay()` should work. May be script is not loaded properly..

Comment: Please check this in your IE. I have loaded jQuery 1.4... http://jsfiddle.net/ABkBa/1/