# jQuery is not Working in UpdatePanels in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am using asp .net update panel.
I got a good reference from 
[[jQuery $(document).ready and UpdatePanels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels)

But in my case i am using a bunch of jquery right from validation to select search and many more.
Can any one suggest me some way so that i can reload those query without writing them again for asynchronous post-backs.

Comment: Please help me...i read many tutorials but could not solve my prob yet

Answer (score 2):

keep your jquery function inside pageload...for example:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
           // your function
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use the below code instead of $(document).ready(YourFunctionName);

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(YourFunctionName)
```

This should work