# jQuery UI class dissapears on button even though .button() is set in codebehind?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui

Im starting to pull my hair over this.

Im trying to append jQuery UI's button appearance on my regular button, however it doesn't get appended. Doesnt even get a class..

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="CartUpdPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server">
    <button runat="server" ID="CheckoutCartButton" CausesValidation="False" EnableViewState="False">Checkout</button>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="CheckoutCartButton" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I want the button to have a secondary icon. I usually know how to make this happen. But I'm running into problems..

This is the checkout button for my cart (I had the disabling working fine before I wanted to make it look fancy), and in the code behind it checks if you have enough credit to checkout or not, enabling/disabling the button.

I cant create the button in a  in the ascx file because it will over-write the disabling of the button, making it enabled:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "disable button", "console.log('disabled'); $('#" + CheckoutCartButton.ClientID + "').button({ icons: { secondary: 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-e' }, disabled: true });", true);
```

I've tried using the updatepanel's id as control, but to no further success. And while writing this I thought it was a page-life cycle problem, since the cart credit is being checked OnInit. But even though I changed it to PageLoad, no difference.

Any wise people out there see my problem?

Comment: Check in resulting html button Id - often asp.net adds container id to control id.

Comment: And also, on postback of update panel, you need to reapply javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels

Comment: @VikciaR Im using ClientID to prevent the weird id that asp.net changes it to, and the problem is ONLY at the first page visit. After postback it actually changes to the right button..

Comment: @Blade0rz Why would you remove C# from the title when its a major part of the question?

Comment: @Cammy Because it is already tagged C#. It is primarily about the disappearance of the jQuery UI class therefore I left that in the title for context.

Comment: @Blade0rz Funny how the answer to the question had to do with C#...

Comment: Are you sure? How do you know MelanciaUK's answer isn't written in VB? My *opinion* was that your question ASP.NET related, not necessarily C#

Comment: @Blade0rz Well _You_ obvious have no idea. Part of the code I posted in my question is C#, thus why I wrote C# and not VB in the header.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I'd like to know your opinion.

Comment: In fact, nevermind, just in case you take offense. You were right, I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just attaching to the wrong method.

Instead of `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`, use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`.

Also, enclose your script with `$(function () { })` so it will be executed when the page is fully loaded.

Should solve your problem.

Comment: And what will be after UpdatePanel refresh?

Comment: I can't remember from the top of my head, as I've been working on MVC for a while. Would you mind testing it?

Comment: Yes thank you, I just came to that conclusion on my own and was about to answer my own question ;)

Comment: @VikciaR Updatepanel refresh wont be a problem since the type being called is the update panel and not the Page.
As in: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(CartUpdPanel, CartUpdPanel.GetTy.... CartUpdPanel being the updatepanel!

Comment: No, I mean that after UpdatePanel you need reapply jquery.button. How to do it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels

Comment: I think it would work perfectly, because on that other post, the OP is having a problem with scripts added to the page (like static). Here, it's being registered on every `PostBack`.