# Jquery Click event does not fire on 2nd time in UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My theme is to display a div showing message "Saved Successfully.." and hide automatically after 2 seconds.
I have done almost all the things and all works fine, but only for the first click. On the 2nd click, it only shows DIV message `enter code here` "Saved Successfully.." but does not execute the query as it should.
I searched a lot on internet but found nothing use full. My code is :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'>
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(function () { // re-bind your jquery events here
            $("#btn_Save").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#showMessage').fadeIn(100);
            setTimeout(function () { $('#showMessage').fadeOut(500); }, 2000);
            })
        })
     })
    </script
```

>

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">  
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="msg" style="display:none" ><p>Saved Successfully...</p></div>                                         <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>        
        </div
            <div id="showMessage" style="display:none;"><p>Saved Successfully...</p>   </div>  
            </ContentTemplate> 
                <Triggers >
                  <%--<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />--%>
                </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>

protected void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Query to save data into database

}
```

Comment: Can be a timing issue can you change your code to:$('#showMessage').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    setTimeout(function () { $('#showMessage').fadeOut(500); }, 2000);
})

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event initially in document.ready and rebind outside:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn_Save").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#showMessage').fadeIn(100);
            setTimeout(function () { $('#showMessage').fadeOut(500); }, 2000);
            })

    })

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function () { // re-bind your jquery events here
        $("#btn_Save").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#showMessage').fadeIn(100);
        setTimeout(function () { $('#showMessage').fadeOut(500); }, 2000);
        })
    })

</script>
```

This post may help: [jQuery $(document).ready and UpdatePanels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels)