# How to make JQuery masked-input plugin working after AsyncPostback in asp.net Ajax Update pannel?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a simple `.aspx` page and a textbox which I want to maske It using `jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js` and my page .aspx code is as follows , the issue is on first page load I the textbox is masked , but after an asyncPostback the masked input plugin is not working !  how can I make the masked input plugin working ? thx in advance .

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $("#txtMembershipCode").mask("999-9999-999-9999");
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager> 
    <div style="float: right" id="exDiv">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div style="float: right; width: 120px; font-family: Tahoma">
                            membership Code :</div>
                        <div style="float: left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMembershipCode" runat="server" CssClass="input" ClientIDMode="Static"
                                dir="ltr"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div style="font-family: Tahoma; float: left">
                            <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="save" OnClick="btn_Click" CssClass="mybtn" /></div>
                        <div style="font-family: Tahoma; float: right">
                            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
                                <ProgressTemplate>
                                    <img src="Images/484.gif" />
                                </ProgressTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdateProgress>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried many different ways on the web but none of them are working !

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery $(document).ready and UpdatePanels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels)

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy Tried It did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way of solving this -

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.onload = function () {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
        }

        function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            init();
        }

        function init() {
            $("#<%=txtMembershipCode.ClientID %>").mask("999-9999-999-9999");
        }

        $(function() { // DOM ready
            init();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager> 
    <div style="float: right" id="exDiv">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div style="float: right; width: 120px; font-family: Tahoma">
                            membership Code :</div>
                        <div style="float: left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMembershipCode" runat="server" CssClass="input" dir="ltr"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div style="font-family: Tahoma; float: left">
                            <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="save" OnClick="btn_Click" CssClass="mybtn" /></div>
                        <div style="font-family: Tahoma; float: right">
                            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
                                <ProgressTemplate>
                                    <img src="Images/484.gif" />
                                </ProgressTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdateProgress>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This approach uses the [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager JavaScript class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.ASPX) and is possible because you have a [Script Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) on your `.aspx` page.  Basically after every async postback the `init()` function will be called.

Notice the `init()` function is also called in DOM ready.  This allows you to do everything to the DOM you need done again after content has changed during the async postback.  I have used this technique before using various jQuery plugins including this one.

Comment: Hi , thx for your answear , I tried exactly your code but at this line of  code : $("#txtMembershipCode").mask("999-9999-999-9999"); I get this error message in runtime : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'mask'

Comment: @Karamafrooz I edited my answer, please try it now.  I think the issue might have something to do with the `ClientIDMode` set to `Static` on the `txtMembershipCode` TextBox.  I removed this and changed the selector so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I used function pageLoad

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

        function pageLoad() {
            $("#<%=txtMembershipCode.ClientID %>").mask("999-9999-999-9999");
        }

</script>
```