# CSS Not carrying over to new tab content

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I have an app that is using a Jquery Tab control for navigation. All of the Jquery and Jquery UI work fine on the master page and on the first tab, once I navigate to the second tab, my theme roller stylings do not carry over. When I navigate quickly back and forth, I can see the styling gets applied and it flashes back to a normal gray button.

This is the button on my page in code

```
<td><input type="button" class="button" runat="server" role="button" value="Run New Claims Query"/></td>
```

The only way I can get it to render how I want is to explicitly state the classes used for styling it

```
<td><input id="open" class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="button" value="Run New Claims Query" name="open" role="button" aria-disabled="false"/></td>
```

Comment: Most jquery based widgets expect a certain DOM structure in order to apply their classes correctly. The `ui-xxxx` classes are applied by jqueryUI on initialization of the widget. If the classes are not being automatically applied it means your DOM/HTML is not structured properly. Either a bad tag, or extra tags that break the flow or something. HTML validation might help spot the error.

Comment: check if the parent elements of first tab and second tab having the same class names or both tabs are under same parent

Comment: @mastaBlasta I ran it through the validator and it passed fine.

Comment: @NishadNichoos the elements on the first on second tab have the same class names and are under the same parent

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where my CSS would show up on initial load of the page but if I performed a postback I would lose my CSS, particularly my jquery ui CSS. I found this answer.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   // bind your jQuery events here initially 
}); 

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 

prm.add_endRequest(function() { 
    // re-bind your jQuery events here 
});
```

Thanks to [jQuery $(document).ready and UpdatePanels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels/256253#256253)

This solved all my vanishing CSS problems. I hope it helps you as well!

Comment: This would probably not work since the OP is not using UpdatePanels and does not have access to that library. Re-adding event handlers on elements can cause memory leaks if they're not properly delegated.